# Get shortest number Algorithm, in actionscript syntax

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I want to put shortest int in `shortest`:

```
shortest = 500;

for(i = 1; i <= _global.var_process_count; i++)
{
    if(_root["process" + i].process_time_original.text < shortest)
        shortest = _root["process" + i].process_time_original.text ;

}
```

what's wrong with above lines of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The code is not ActionScript-3, it is either AS-2 or lower.
- You are not casting the string (`textfield.text`) to a `Number`.
- What if the smallest number is 501 (or anything greater than 500)?

Try the following code:

```
var shortest:Number = Number.MAX_VALUE; 
for(i = 1; i <= _global.var_process_count; i++) 
{
  var t:Number = Number(_root["process" + i].process_time_original.text);
  if(isNaN(t)) //in case the text is not a valid number.
    continue;
  if(t < shortest) 
    shortest = t;
}
trace("shortest number is " + shortest);
```

Comment: @teehoo neither an `_root`; That's exactly why I said that the code is not AS3 and retagged the question accordingly.

Comment: yh, i apologize it was not as3 and this thing worked:
 var shortest:int; 
 shortest = _global.var_process_time;  
 var GoFor:int;  
 for(i = 1; i <= _global.var_process_count; i++) 
 {
   var t:Number;
   t = Number(_root["process" + i].process_time_original.text);
    if(isNaN(t)) //in case the text is not a valid number.
      continue;
   if(t < shortest && _root["process" + i].process_played == 0) 
   {
  shortest = t;  
  GoFor = i;
   }
 }
 _root["process" + GoFor].playState = 1;